# jQuery is preventing default action, but is not supposed to be

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this line of jQuery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".thumbs a.dlink").live("click", function() { 
    alert("yo");
});
```

On a link I originally included, there was a return false in the code that was preventing the page from working as intended.  The alert was just me testing, but it turns out that alerts will delay any current page actions until it is closed.

Thanks so much everyone!

EDIT: sorry for any confusion this may have caused.  Moral of the story - watch out for return false's!

Comment: "you see the popup and only after you press okay does the link open up." Yes, and what's the error? Javascript runs in a single thread so that is absolutely expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't get it? Are you expecting the new page to load, and then to have the alert popup? If so, it doesn't work that way !

Comment: I am eventually trying to run aJax, so clearly, I wasn't clear enough!  When I press  the download button, I want the link to open regardless of whether or not the aJax is successful.

Comment: Why would you do you an ajax call, just to redirect anyway ?

Comment: @adeneo it's a counter to add to the download count!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `return false` in your code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".thumbs a.dlink").live("click", function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); //$("#galid").val();
        id = id.substr(1);
        alert("yo"); 
        $.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
            action : 'download_counter',
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
            id : id
        },function(response) {} );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.alert` function pauses the JavaScript on the page and is modal, so nothing will happen until the user closes the dialog. My recommendation for an alternative would be to create your own alert dialog in html, or use one of the many library/plugins out there e.g. [jQuery UI's dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), and use that for your messages in lieu of alert. Since you're just adding a dom element, nothing's pausing your scripts and any async functions will run normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
<div id='dialog-yo' title='Download In Progress'>Yo</div>
<div class='thumbs'><a class="dlink" dlTitle='my cool image'>try this now</a></div>
<script>
  $(function() {

    $( '#dialog-yo' ).dialog({
      modal: false,
      autoOpen: false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      draggable: true,
      hide: 'slide',
      show: 'fade',
      resizable: true,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      zIndex: 200,
      buttons: {
        'Yeah, Okay': function() { $( '#dialog-yo' ).dialog('close'); }
      }
    });

    $(".thumbs a.dlink").live("click", function() { 
      $( '#dialog-yo' ).dialog('open').html(this.getAttribute('dlTitle'));
    });        

  });
</script>
```

After viewing your site I am not sure the purpose of your notification, but hopefully this gets you going in a flexible direction from which you can continue.